# Shodan - Python Syntax to use "Info" Tag

Tags: python, shodan

So I'm currently working on a script using Shodan in Python using `import shodan`.
The documentation around isn't the best so id thought I'd bring my issue here.

Using the Shodan CLI there is a command known as `Shodan Info` which displays the number of search credits that your account has remaining.

When looking at the [Shodan Documentation](https://shodan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#shodan.Shodan.delete_alert) i can see that there is an `info()` tag but whenever I use it there has been an error.

**Does anyone know the correct syntax for using info in a python script to display the number of credits an account has?**

Errors i have received:

```
ipinfo = shodan.info()
print (ipinfo)
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/XXXX/OneDrive - XXXX/Documents/XX Documents/XXXX/Working 
                                             Segments/ShodanScraper.py", line 8, in <module>
ipinfo = shodan.info()
AttributeError: module 'shodan' has no attribute 'info'
```

And

```
ipinfo = shodan.Shodan(info())
print (ipinfo)
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/XXXX/OneDrive - XXXX/Documents/XXXXDocuments/XXXXXX/Working 
                                             Segments/ShodanScraper.py", line 8, in <module>
ipinfo = shodan.Shodan(info())
NameError: name 'info' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `Shodan` class and then you will be able to use its `Shodan.info()` method. Here is how it looks in the official command-line interface:

https://github.com/achillean/shodan-python/blob/master/shodan/__main__.py#L364

Here's a short script that prints the current account usage information:

```py
import pprint
import shodan

key = 'YOUR API KEY'
api = shodan.Shodan(key)
results = api.info()
pprint.pprint(results)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. 

Not as concise as the CLI format but it has a format that can be put straight into a dictionary. ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.{'scan_credits': 100, 'usage_limits': {'scan_credits': 100, 'query_credits': 100, 'monitored_ips': 16}, 'plan': 'dev', 'https': False, 'unlocked': True, 'query_credits': 91, 'monitored_ips': None, 'unlocked_left': 91, 'telnet': False}

Comment: The ``Shodan.info()`` method returns a dictionary so you don't need to convert it into anything. And you can get the same concise format as the CLI if you want - just print the ``scan_credits`` and ``query_credits`` properties.

Comment: Ah, yes, ill use that. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

shodan does not express how to use info. heres a breif example of how to set up shodan info

```
import shodan
api = shodan.Shodan('YOUR API KEY')

info = api.host('8.8.8.8')
shodan info
```

Comment: Useful, but this displayed information about the host rather than my account. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: @Verudux of course sorry I cant be much help I've never worked with shodan